# Getting warning in function vPortStartFirstTask during compilation of freeRTOS but program is working

Tags: c

Whenever I am compiling my project in freeRTOS am getting the following warning.

> /port.c: In function 'vPortStartFirstTask':
>   ../../../../third_party/RTOS/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/port.c:194:1:
>   warning: stack usage computation not supported for this target
>   [enabled by default]  }  ^

This is the function

```
void vPortStartFirstTask( void )
{
    /* The MSP stack is not reset as, unlike on M3/4 parts, there is no vector
    table offset register that can be used to locate the initial stack value.
    Not all M0 parts have the application vector table at address 0. */

    __asm volatile(
    "   ldr r2, pxCurrentTCBConst2  \n" /* Obtain location of pxCurrentTCB. */
    "   ldr r3, [r2]                \n"
    "   ldr r0, [r3]                \n" /* The first item in pxCurrentTCB is the task top of stack. */
    "   add r0, #32                 \n" /* Discard everything up to r0. */
    "   msr psp, r0                 \n" /* This is now the new top of stack to use in the task. */
    "   movs r0, #2                 \n" /* Switch to the psp stack. */
    "   msr CONTROL, r0             \n"
    "   pop {r0-r5}                 \n" /* Pop the registers that are saved automatically. */
    "   mov lr, r5                  \n" /* lr is now in r5. */
    "   cpsie i                     \n" /* The first task has its context and interrupts can be enabled. */
    "   pop {pc}                    \n" /* Finally, pop the PC to jump to the user defined task code. */
    "                               \n"
    "   .align 2                    \n"
    "pxCurrentTCBConst2: .word pxCurrentTCB   "
                  );
}
```

Please help me to eliminate the particular warning and anybody please tell me why am getting this.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want -fstack-usage for everything else but I specifically want to disable it for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this warning because you are trying to compile your program with [GCC's stack usage analysis](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Static-Stack-Usage-Analysis.html) turned on, but it's not supported on your platform.

To eliminate it, compile your program without the `-fstack-usage` compiler switch - which is probably added by your makefile, or IDE, I'm not sure how do you build your project.